# Can't refactor a meteor HTTP request function

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm a newbie with meteor/js so really sorry if this is a dumb question.

The old function is like this:

```
import {HTTP} from 'meteor/http';

export function AccountLogin(data, url) {

    console.log('test header');
    // console.log(header);
    HTTP.post(url, {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Client_id': 'test',
            'Client_secret': '1234'

        },
        npmRequestOptions: {
            rejectUnauthorized: false,
            strictSSL: false,
            timeout: 1000
        },

        data: JSON.stringify(data)
    }, function (error, response) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            console.log(response);
            console.log(response.statusCode);
            console.log(response.content);
        }
    });
}
```

And called like this:

```
import {Meteor} from 'meteor/meteor';
import {AccountLogin} from "../import/AccountCaller";

Meteor.startup(() => {
    // code to run on server at startup
    const data = {
        "username": "test",
        "password": "test"
    };
    console.log(data.username);
    let url = 'https://localhost:5001/api/account/authenticate';
    const headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Client_id': 'test',
        'Client_secret': '1234'

    };
    AccountLogin(data, url);

});
```

I want to move the header to the params, so I do this:

```
    export function AccountLogin(data, url, header) {


        HTTP.post(url, {
            header,
//... the rest
```

And modify the call in the main,

```
AccountLogin(data, url ,header);
```

The server response is different when move header to the param. I wonder I did something wrong when refactor this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a simple typo:

```js
HTTP.post(url, {
  headers: header, // or rename your 3rd argument as "headers" (notice the trailing "s")
  npmRequestOptions,
  data
}, callback);
```